# HTACCESS: manipulating/changing URLS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, localhost

Thank you for taking your time to read this,

Lets say for example i have a folder called "ADMIN" and in there i have 3 files named

```
file1.php
file2.php
file3.php
```

so when i visit them it would be like this right?

```
http://localhost/admin/file1.php
http://localhost/admin/file2.php
http://localhost/admin/file3.php
```

now is there any way i can change these to

```
http://localhost/admin/file1/
http://localhost/admin/file2/
http://localhost/admin/file3/
```

i know there is a way to do this individually but i don't have 3 files in there theres more like 25 so it would be a bit of a pain.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Also as a little extra. This could be a stupid or a good question but is there any way to hide "GET" data with .htaccess for example

```
http://localhost/file.php?get=name
```

to

```
http://localhost/file.php
```

and also the get data still work obviously.

Thanks again.

Connor

Comment: There are literally hundreds of questions on StackOverflow that cover either exactly this or similar questions.  Try searching.

Comment: Do you know one then, because i couldn't find any that  rewrite a whole folder

Comment: Search.  Try the **Related** section over there -->

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the `.php` extension should look something like this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-\.]*)?$ /admin/$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

As for GET data, can't you send those parameters as POST from your form(s)?

Comment: Hi, i get a 500 with this

Comment: make sure mod_rewrite is turned on, and look at your log files.